# How can I use property functions in methods in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried writing Code 2 to do the same thing as Code 1. But, Code 2 did not work. Why? How can I use property functions in methods in python?

(Code 1)

```
class Spam:
    def __init__(self, is_less_sodium):
        self.__is_less_sodium = is_less_sodium

    def __getter(self):
        return self.__is_less_sodium

    is_less_sodium = property(__getter)

my_spam = Spam(False)
print(my_spam.is_less_sodium)

########## Result ##########
# False
```

(Code 2)

```
class Spam:
    def __init__(self, is_less_sodium):
        self.__is_less_sodium = is_less_sodium
        Spam.is_less_sodium = property(self.__getter)

    def __getter(self):
        return self.__is_less_sodium

my_spam = Spam(False)
print(my_spam.is_less_sodium)

########## Result ##########
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "code2.py", line 10, in <module>
#     print(my_spam.is_less_sodium)
# TypeError: __getter() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I understood that the return value of `property(__getter)` is assigned to `is_less_sodium`, which is a class variable of `Spam`, in Code 1. But, this understanding seems wrong.

Comment: That style you are using is an old style. Try the new, decorator style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Spam:
    def __init__(self, is_less_sodium):
        self.__is_less_sodium = is_less_sodium
        Spam.is_less_sodium = property(Spam.__getter,)

    def __getter(self):
        return self.__is_less_sodium

my_spam = Spam(False)
print(my_spam.is_less_sodium)
```

You can use that syntax but you also have to reference the function from the class level not the instance function.

The decorator syntax is much cleaner.

```
class Spam:
    def __init__(self, is_less_sodium):
        self.__is_less_sodium = is_less_sodium

    @property
    def is_less_sodium(self):
        return self.__is_less_sodium

    @is_less_sodium.setter
    def set_is_less_sodium(self):
        self.__is_less_sodium

my_spam = Spam(False)
print(my_spam.is_less_sodium)
my_spam.is_less_sodium = True
print(my_spam.is_less_sodium)
```

Comment: This is correct, however there is no point in complicating the code with decorators that do  nothing different from a regular attribute. Just make `is_less_sodium` a regular attribute (with that name).

Answer (score 0):

In code1, property is used as `property(__getter)`. In this code, `__getter` accepts 1 argument `self`.

In code2, property is used as `property(self.__getter)`. In this code, `self.__getter` accepts no argument.

In use case of code2, `my_spam.is_less_sodium` will result `my_spam.__getter(my_spam)`.

This is the cause of error message `__getter() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`